# Concatenate two strings together, but have the first line be on the same line in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, concatenation

If I had two strings, `a` and `b`, and they were defined as the following:

```
a = "Hello\nSome"
b = "World\nText"
```

How would I concatenate them together in such a way that all the characters on the first line would be in the first line on the resultant string, and example:

```py
def Odd_Concat_Function(i1,i2):
   [...]
[...]
c = Odd_Concat_Function(a,b)
print (c)
```

With the desired output being:

```
Hello World
Some Text
```

How would I achieve this for an arbitrary number of strings?

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: Is there not enough information in the question?

Comment: This website is not a code-writing service. We are here to help you with specific problems in your own code.

Comment: And I'm not using it for that. I am simply asking about a problem and I have tried various ways of fixing it. However, I have written a large chunk of code to do this task and it would not fit in the post. Case and point why it is not included.

Comment: I get that, but you have to look at it from our point of view. We only see what you have posted. It greatly encourages us when we see actual effort on your part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following. This splits and rejoins the arguments appropriately:

```
def Odd_Concat_Function(i1, i2):
    return "\n".join(" ".join(p) for p in zip(*(x.split("\n") for x in (i1, i2))))

>>> c = Odd_Concat_Function(a,b)
>>> print (c)
Hello World
Some Text
```

You can make it more general to allow any number of such strings:

```
def Odd_Concat_Function(*args):
    return "\n".join(map(" ".join, zip(*(x.split("\n") for x in args))))

>>> print(Odd_Concat_Function('Hello\nSome', 'World\nText', 'more\nstuff'))
Hello World more
Some Text stuff
```

See some of the docs:

- [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)
- [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)
- [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)
- [unpacking arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments)

Comment: Even in the generic case, I would still be inclined to use a generator expression rather than `map` for the outer loop: `"\n".join(" ".join(p) for p in zip(*(x.split("\n") for x in args)))`

Comment: I will leave it to show both. Also, I usually go with `map` if there is a function ready to be used which is the case here. The generator or comprehension would be definitely advisable if you had to force a `lambda` into the map otherwise.